# Swing JSplitPane - Is there a way to listen to a click on the divider's arrows?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to catch the event when the small "minimize" or "maximize" arrows of a JSplitPane's divider are clicked.

I found a way to listen to a click *elsewhere* on the divider bar. Something like  :

```
SplitPaneUI spui = splitPane.getUI();
if (spui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
    ((BasicSplitPaneUI) spui).getDivider().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // do something...
        }
    });
}
```

But is there a way to listen to clicks on the *arrows*?

Comment: To what end?  What is it you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to catch the event when the small "minimize" or "maximize" arrows of a JSplitPane's divider are clicked.

Maybe you could add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JSPlitPane` and listen for `dividerLocation` changes (assuming you don't care if the divider was dragged or "one clicked" to the start or end). Then you can check if the divider location is at 0 or the maximum.

```
splitPane.addPropertyChangeListener("dividerLocation", this);

...

public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
{
    //  Get the new divider location of the split pane

    int location = ((Integer)e.getNewValue()).intValue();

    if (location == 0)
        //  do something
    else if (location == splitPane.getMaximumDividerLocation())
        //  do something else
}
```

If you do care about the difference between dragging and clicking, then maybe you can compare the old/new values and look for a change in the location greater than a specified value.

Another option is to get the button from the divider:

```
JSplitPane splitPane = (JSplitPane)e.getSource();
BasicSplitPaneUI ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI)splitPane.getUI();
BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = ui.getDivider();
JButton button1 = (JButton)divider.getComponent(0)
```

Now you can add another ActionListener to the button to do your custom code.

Comment: But this will fire even if you drag the divider via mouse right.

Comment: @Madhan, which is why I suggested it may help. I never understand applications where clicking the divider to 0, versus dragging the divider to 0, results in a different action. So I suggested this approach which is the simplest to implement.

Comment: I actually used a variation on this code. But it should be : `else if (location >= splitPane.getMaximumDividerLocation())` not `else if (location == splitPane.getMaximumDividerLocation())` ! The thing is that `splitPane.getMaximumDividerLocation()` doesn't return the maximum position of the divider bar when maximized using the arrow, it returns the maximum location of the divider bar *if dragged by the user*. When dragged, the divider bar will refuse to go pass a certain position which would hide the content of its component entirely. This limitation doesn't exist when clicking the arrow.

Comment: @electrotype `When dragged, the divider bar will refuse to go pass a certain position` - yes, I believe dragging respects the minimum size of the component. If you want to be able to drag to the extreme then override the minimum size of the component.

Comment: You should also know that you can use `F8` to place focus on the divider. Then you can use the `Home` and `End` keys to change the divider location.

Answer (score 3):

Reflection is the Only way I guess to listen to One Touch Expandable Buttons

Just pass `addSplitPaneListener` and it is done.

```
public void addSplitPaneListener(JSplitPane splitPane) {
    addSplitPaneListener("leftButton", splitPane);
    addSplitPaneListener("rightButton", splitPane);
}

public void addSplitPaneListener(String button, JSplitPane splitPane) {
    try {
        Field field = BasicSplitPaneDivider.class.getDeclaredField(button);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        JButton onetouchButton = (JButton) field.get(((BasicSplitPaneUI) splitPane.getUI()).getDivider());
        onetouchButton.setActionCommand(button);
        onetouchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttonClicked(e);
            }
        });
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void buttonClicked(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Clicked " + e.getActionCommand());
}
```

Comment: What I actually did in the end was inspired by @camickr answer, but I feel this one is the one that really answers the question I asked.

Comment: I didn't see @camickr modified his answer to add a way to get the buttons, without using reflection. I'm going with his answer after all. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a derived class that deals with expanding/hiding either using the one touch expander and/or an additional keylistener bound to a certain key to hide/unhide the RIGHT panel. Doing it for the left should easy to adapt ;)

Interestingly on Linux the right part will never get its theoretical maximum value but will be one less (BUGCLICKONETOUCH). Didn't test if this is also true on Windows.

```java
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class JToggleSplitPane extends JSplitPane {

  private int restoreWidth = -1;
  private final static int BUGCLICKONETOUCH = 1; 

  public JToggleSplitPane(int splittype, Component c1, Component c2) {
    super(splittype, c1, c2);
    setOneTouchExpandable(true);
  }

  public void toggle() {
    try {
      if (getDividerLocation() < getWidth() - getDividerSize() - BUGCLICKONETOUCH) {
        restoreWidth = getWidth() - getDividerSize() - getDividerLocation();
        setDividerLocation(1.0d);
      } else {
        setDividerLocation(getWidth() - getDividerSize() - restoreWidth);
      }
      updateUI();
      doLayout();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void doLayout() {
    super.doLayout();
    if (restoreWidth == -1) {
      restoreWidth = rightComponent.getWidth();
    }
  }
}
```